# Not able to convert underscore case to camel case with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

I have a `DTO` class which has a property like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class WPPostResponse {
    @JsonProperty("featuredMedia")
    Long featured_media;

    public Long getFeatured_media() {
        return featured_media;
    }

    public void setFeatured_media(Long featured_media) {
        this.featured_media = featured_media;
    }
}
```

The input JSON has the key `featured_media`. I convert the JSON string to the object and then sends it to the client response as JSON. I want the final response JSON to have `featuredMedia` as the key. I am however getting `null` as the value. If I remove the `JsonProperty`, it gives the value, but the key is having underscore. How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always respect the Java naming conventions in your Java code. Use annotations to deal with Json not respecting them.

In this case, use [`JsonAlias`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html)

> Annotation that can be used to define one or more alternative names for a property, accepted during deserialization as alternative to the official name

```
public class WPPostResponse {
    @JsonAlias("featured_media")
    Long featuredMedia;

    public Long getFeaturedMedia() {
        return featuredMedia;
    }

    public void setFeaturedMedia(Long featuredMedia) {
        this.featuredMedia = featuredMedia;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) on setters and getters to have different namings during serialization and deserialization

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class WPPostResponse {

   Long featuredMedia;

   @JsonProperty("featuredMedia")    // output will be featuredMedia
   public Long getFeatured_media() {
       return featuredMedia;
   }

   @JsonProperty("featured_media")    // input should be featured_media
   public void setFeatured_media(Long featured_media) {
       this.featuredMedia = featured_media;
   }
}
```

And also you set access level to `@JsonProperty` annotation

```
@JsonProperty(value = "featured_media", access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
```